# Can I deactivate Hibernate outside transactions to avoid LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, jpa

### **EDIT** - I have solved my specific problem with jackson/hibernate using the library https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-hibernate. The solution was not the one I searched for here, but it is equally valid in my situation.

Original question:

I have recently come across the infamous `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` when using Hibernate/Spring/Jackson. The problem for me occurs when jackson tries to serialize and object, finds an attribute that is a lazy-fetched value and tires to access it. I have read a lot of questions, posts and discussions about this but the proposed solution always seems to be a variant of two alternatives

- Make sure that the lazy attributes are loaded before the transaction ends.
- Configure jackson to ignore the attribute.

I wonder if there is another solution because the fact is that when my service returns a Hibernate object with some attributes not initialized, then I want to display the object in that manner. Configuring jackson for the specific purpose seems to be a strategy where the presentation layer needs intricate knowledge of the database layer and that seems like a bad solution.

The way I would like it to work from my initial look at the frameworks is that whenever a Hibernate entity is accessed outside a transaction, hibernate should not care about the object and it should act like a normal POJO. In essence:

1. Start a transaction
2. Perform CRUD operations on Hibernate managed objects.
3. End the transaction and possibly return fetched/modified objects that can be used read/altered without events propagating to the underlying database.

Example of desired behaviour:

```
//Start transaction
MyEntity entity = entityManager.find(primaryKey, MyEntity.class);
entity.getLazyLoadedFooList(); //Load the list from database
//End transaction
entity.getLazyLoadedBarList(); //Return null instead of throw LazyInitializationException
```

The basic idea is that the applications has a presentation, service and a DAO layer. The DAO layer is concerned with CRUD operations against the database. The Service layer wraps DAO methods in transactions and returns java objects that represent the data that was asked for. These objects are then available to to the presentation layer which converts them *as they are* to the desired format, in this case JSON.

Two questions about this:

- Can it be done like I describe or in some similar fashion?
- Is it a good/bad idea?

Comment: are you using a web application? also what is the application framework used? ex spring

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes currently I am working on a web application using Spring MVC

Comment: you can make use of http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html

Comment: @ArunPJohny Wouldn't that cause all the lazy attributes to be fetched? I do not want them to be fetched.

Comment: It will not be fetched unless it is accessed, it will not do a eager fetch. What it does is keep the session open through out the request

Comment: @ArunPJohny But they _are_ accessed when jackson converts the object to json. Jackson accesses all attributes and reads their values.

Comment: in that case you need to properly configure the jackson serializer using annotations. like asking the serializer not to serialize the unwanted fields.

Comment: @ArunPJohny It seems like you have offered me two solutions that I explicitly state in my question that I have already seen on different forums and that I explain that I do not want to use.

Comment: sorry I missed that point. In that case I think you are out of luck because jackson work based using properties, getters/setters

Answer (score 0):

After fetching the entity, you can `detach` that from the hibernate Session.

You will not get any `LazyInitializationException` after that (but the lazy fields will be null).

So following your example:

```
   //Start transaction
   MyEntity entity = entityManager.find(primaryKey, MyEntity.class);
   entity.getLazyLoadedFooList(); //Load the list from database
   //End transaction
    entityManager.clear(); // detaches the enitities
    entity.getLazyLoadedBarList(); //Return null instead of throw LazyInitializationException
```

Comment: I still get the same error. The documentation for the method clear says: "Clear the persistence context, causing all managed entities to become detached. Changes made to entities that have not been flushed to the database will not be persisted." No mentioning of read operations. Could it be that changes in detached objects are not persisted but read-operations are still performed?

Comment: What JPA provider are you using? Hibernate?

Comment: I've tried both clear and detach. Nothing helps. I'm using Hibernate 5.x What do I do wrong? Yes, I do want to get null when trying to access lazy non-initialized entity field.

Comment: `detach` belongs to EntityManager (JPA). For Hibernate, the equivalent is `Session.evict`

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following code to change the entity from a hibernate entity to a regular POJO. I use it for the purpose of reading annotations on the class that exist in my code but not in the hibernate proxy.

```
import org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy;

public class StripHibernateProxy {

    // This function takes the hibernate entity and forces it to be a real java
    // object instead

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T initializeAndUnproxy(T entity) {

            if (entity == null) {
                    throw new NullPointerException("Entity passed for initialization is null");
            }

            Hibernate.initialize(entity);

            if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
                    entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
            }

            return entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simply call `org.hibernate.Hibernate#unproxy(object)`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any real answer to this question?  I've been obsessed with it for years and only found a few hack solutions like Gilead or the Jackson-hibernate module.  It would be nice if hibernate would honor the POJO contract and not throw exceptions, at least if it was set to do so.  Maybe some kind of hint similar to the read only one.

```
List<Customer> list = em.createQuery(q, Customer.class)
            .setParameter("lastName", "Vest")
            .setHint("org.hibernate.readOnly", true)
            .getResultList();
```